# Best Sorting Algorithm for BurrowsWheeler Transform (BWT)

Tags: java, algorithm

I'm stuck on a bit of a problem with the Burrows Wheeler Transformation. It's a college project, but this is a very small part of it. The entire project consists of 3 different algorithms being put together for data compression.

I am just trying to figure out what would be the most memory and time efficient sorting algorithm to use for the suffix sorting in the Burrows Wheeler Transformation? The encoding needs to be as efficient as possible.

With smaller arrays the sorting won't really effect it really, but while the text files that we are compressing get bigger and bigger the time consumed using an inefficient sorting alrogithm really destroys the time and memory efficiency.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

We code in Java by the way, just realized I never mentioned that.

Comment: If there aren't any special properties required of the sort, what's wrong with quick, heap or merge, optionally swapping to insertion sort for sufficiently small subarrays?

Comment: Nothing is wrong with them, I am using quick sort for the moment. I was just asking for some opinions on the most efficient algorithm to be used for this specific example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Many practical BWT based compression tools are based on **DivSufSort** and **MSufSort**. but they have O(n^2) worst performance, you have to use some preprocessing methods on your data before sorting.

For best time/space cost in theory, try **sa-is** and **sa-ds**.

If you are trying to write a suffix sorting algorithm yourself, I suggest you start from fast and simple **QSufSort**.

Comment: And I suggest you not use java for a compression tool project, it's too slow.

Comment: Actually Java is not slow :-)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by richselian, sorting is quadratic while suffix array based algorithms are linear. If your arrays are small, it does not matter but bigger arrays yield better compression results. You can find a complete java implementation of a BWT based on suffix arrays here as an example: https://code.google.com/p/kanzi/source/browse/java/src/kanzi/transform/BWT.java (arrays up to 16MB).
As for the argument, "java is slow", I would respectfully disagree.